# Can I change title text color in UITableVIew? (swift)

Tags: swift, text, colors, title

I know it's kinda stupid question, but I have really stuck there. So now I'm trying to make my tableView look better and as you can see I'm using CAGradientLayer to make a custom background for it, but also you can see there a "Events" title above the first cell. And exactly that title color i want to change for color green to fit with another content.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jOLw.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UITableView.tableHeaderView Property to create a UIView that sits there. With this property you should be able to customise the view/colour however you like. For example:

```
`var tableHeaderView: UIView? {
   tableHeaderView.backgroundColor = // your colour here
}`
```

or if you've assigned the view in your storyboard to be a class UITableView then just:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView?.backgroundColor = // UIColour(...)
```